# Objdump stops disassembling after label

Tags: arm, label, objdump, linaro

I'm designing an AArch64 application in assembly and C, using Linaro toolchain, and frequently use objdump to look at my own disassembled binary.
However, objdump does not decode part of file, and treats it as data. It always happens after a second label in source.

For example, this code:

```
.global _Reset

_Reset:

BL get_cpuid
CBNZ x0, inf_loop

LDR     x0, =page_table_base      
LDR     x1, =0x0000000000000601 
STR     x1, [x0, #0x00]
test:
LDR     x1, =0x0060000040000601
STR     x1, [x0, #0x08]
...
```

Disassembles to

```
Disassembly of section .startup:

0000000000000000 <_Reset>:
       0: 94000024  bl  90 <get_cpuid>
       4: b50004c0  cbnz  x0, 9c <inf_loop>
       8: 58000880  ldr x0, 118 <TXTN+0x3>
       c: 580008a1  ldr x1, 120 <TXTN+0xb>
      10: f9000001  str x1, [x0]

0000000000000014 <test>:
      14: 580008a1  .word 0x580008a1
      18: f9000401  .word 0xf9000401
...
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You could try to add an `.ltorg`.  It looks like a bug in your `objdump` with AArch64 which is relatively new.  I would guess a bug in the toolchain, in which case it is tough to answer.

Comment: Thank you artless noise! `.ltorg` helps with some parts of my code, if I place it before each label, but does nothing to other parts. And you were right about a bug in a toolchain - after your answer I checked Linaro bug tracker and found this: https://bugs.linaro.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815

Comment: You could summarize the bug post and use it as a reference in an answer (Ie, people need binutils 2.25 or the patch in that bug reference; fairly easy to apply with crosstool-ng).